# c++ program that inputs a sentence from the user and counts the number of words and characters in the sentence

Tags: c++

I am getting an error and also not getting the desired output what wrong could be here. [Error] Empty Character Constant

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int countch=0;
    int countwd=1;

    cout<<"Enter a sentence: "<<endl;
    char ch='a';

    while(ch!='\r')
    {
        ch=getche();

        if(ch=='')
        countwd++;
      
        else
        countch++;
        
    }
    cout<<"\nWords = "<<countwd<<endl;
    cout<<"\nCharacters = "<<countch-1<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(ch=='')` You can't have single quotes with nothing in between - you need to specify some character.  Also are you sure you want '\r' in the loop condition?  Normally you would check for '\n' unless you are reading from some binary file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int character_counter = 0, word_counter = 0;

    cout << "Enter a sentence: " << endl;
    char character, previous_character;

    while (character != '\n'){
        scanf("%c", &character);

        if (character == 32){
            if (character_counter > 0 && previous_character != 32)
                 word_counter++;
        }else{
            if (character != '\n' && character != 32)
                character_counter++;
        }

        previous_character = character;
   }

    if (character_counter > 0){
        word_counter += 1;
    }

    cout << "\nWords = " << word_counter << endl;
    cout << "\nCharacters = " << character_counter << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add space while checking for space and condition for carriage return makes less sense it's better to have check for both '\r' and '\n' .
Moreover I will suggest you to either use C++ or C mixing both will be more prone to errors

```
int main()
{
    int countch=0;
    int countwd=1;

    cout<<"Enter a sentence: "<<endl;
    char ch='a';

    while(ch!='\r' && ch!='\n')
    {
        ch=getche();

        if(ch==' ')
        countwd++;
      
        else
        countch++;
        
    }
    cout<<"\nWords = "<<countwd<<endl;
    cout<<"\nCharacters = "<<countch-1<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int countch=0;
    int countwd=1;
    cout<<"Enter a sentence: "<<endl;
    char ch;
    while(ch!='\r')
    {
        ch=getche();
        if(ch==' '){
            countwd++;
        }else{
            countch++;
        }
    }
    cout<<"\nWords = "<<countwd<<endl;
    cout<<"Characters = "<<countch-1<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Error for empty character constant solved by entering a space constant there, also not initialized the char ch as 'a' and just declared ch;